# Is there an easier way to beat Lilith in Jade Cocoon 2 (PS2)?

Tags: jade-cocoon-2

I've finally finished all the Dark forests (through the Kaya gate) in Jade Cocoon 2 for the PS2, but I'm really stuck on how to beat Lilith (the transformed Levant).

I keep having long battles which don't really amount to much, so I keep resetting without saving so I keep my items.

Does anyone have any strategies that have worked?

Answer (score 1):

this was pulled from a strategy and was written by: Rocky Valkryie.

> Suggested tactic: Hopefully you brought plenty of attack 
>   up and inciting books and it should end well. Also, make sure that one of your fire 
>   beasts has an all-hitting move like soldote. Inciting book+Strong MG user+Inciting 
>   book= First turn smaller-kalma kill. That will leave your 2 other strong attackers 
>   a chance to hit the bigger kalma. Do this till you run out of MP. Hopefully you still 
>   have some books left, too. Now switch to the water side and stall out. Tishalite is 
>   useful to have. Switch back when the MP is up again and repeat the Inciting book+Fire 
>   formation thing. When you run out of books or one or two of your fire formation beasts 
>   die, switch to the wind side. If you have good strong attackers here, that's really good. 
>   When they run out, turn to the earth side. When all else fails, stall out with the water 
>   side to replenish your attackers. That's all my advice.
>   Blockquote